# acentos str_extract()

Tags: r, string

Estou precisando fazer uma análise de livros em português brasileiro. Para organizar uma lista de frequências das palavras por livro estou usando os comandos:

```
GS.tidy <- GS %>%
  unnest_tokens(word, text)
MM.tidy <- MM %>%
  unnest_tokens(word, text)
NS.tidy <- NS %>%
  unnest_tokens(word, text)
Sa.tidy <- Sa %>%
  unnest_tokens(word, text)
frequencia.guimaraes <- bind_rows(mutate(MM.tidy, livro = "MM"),
                                 mutate(GS.tidy, livro = "GS"),
                                 mutate(NS.tidy, livro = "NS"),
                                 mutate(Sa.tidy, livro = "Sa")) %>%
  mutate(word = str_extract(word, "[a-z']+")) %>%
  count(livro, word) %>%
  group_by(livro)
```

Entretanto percebi que as palavras acentuadas estão sumindo e elas precisariam ficar. Há alguma dica?

Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [expressões regulares](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/regex.html) não são iguais em todo o lado, dependem da língua ou país, da *locale* do sistema.

Da página de ajuda de `regex`, com link acima:

> The only portable way to specify all ASCII letters is to list them all
>   as the character class
>   `[ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz]`.

Tradução Google Translate.

> A única forma portátil de especificar todas as letras ASCII é listar
>   todas elas como a classe de caracteres
>   `[ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz]`.

Isto significa que se quisermos a classe de letras da língua portuguesa teremos que incluir as todas letras acentuadas uma a uma. E em português do Brasil haverá ainda as [letras com trema](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trema#Em_Portugal), tais como `"freqüência"`, abolidas em Portugal em 1945.

**Solução.**

No entanto, a solução é simples.
A classe `[:alpha:]` funciona no R, apesar de não ser garantidamente portátil.

```
library(stringr)

s <- c("ate", "até", "freqüencia", "mão")

str_extract(s, "[A-Za-z''`~^]+")
#[1] "ate"  "at"   "freq" "m"  

str_extract(s, "[:alpha:]+")
#[1] "ate"        "até"        "freqüencia" "mão"
```

Comment: Muito obrigado!